# Change the numColumns of the FlatList turns the direction horizontal

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Enabling numColumns = {2}, turns the FlatList on horizontal direction, and with the Scroll blocked.

I want that stays in vertical direction with 2 items per row.

My FlatList

```js
<FlatList
    data={shipments}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    numColumns={2}
    renderItem={({ item: shipmentsArray }) => {
        return shipmentsArray.map((shipment) => {
            return (
                <View
                    key={shipment["delivery no."]}
                    style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={style.shipment}
                    >
                        <Text>Nº Pedido:</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            );
        });
    }}
/>
```

Shipment style

```js
    shipment: {
        width: 160,
        height: 130,
        borderColor: "gray",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        marginBottom: 20,
        marginRight: 20,
        backgroundColor: "#ebebeb",
        flexDirection: "column",
    }
```

Image of the app:
[image: Image of the scenario]

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: The idea is to have two items per row.

Comment: you can use flex-wrap to move item to next line if it is can't fit. The third item will go to next line.